# C# Sockets: synchronous calls within asynchronous ones

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

In MSDN [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of using asynchronous sockets, the receiving data in socket is done by repeatedly calling asynchronous BeginReceive from the callback handler which is called by BeginReceive:

```
private static void ReceiveCallback( IAsyncResult ar ) {
//...Skipped...
        if (bytesRead > 0) {
            // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer,0,bytesRead));
                //  Get the rest of the data.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer,0,StateObject.BufferSize,0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        } else {
// ...Skipped...
}
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Is there a necessity to make again an asynchronous call from a handler which is already executing in a separate thread? Can one simply use Receive in a loop in this handler? Something like:

```
while (bytesRead) {

bytesRead = client.Receive(state.buffer, 0, client.Available, 
                                   SocketFlags.None);
// Etc...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The major goal of the [APM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx) was to avoid blocking the calling thread while waiting for the result of asynchronous operation, and thus boost the scalability of the server applications.

If in your `AsyncCallback` you continue calling `Receive` in the loop synchronously, you'll still be blocking the IOCP thread on which the initial `BeginReceive` has completed. This may be OK for a client-side UI app, where you might not care about `ThreadPool` starvation, but this is certainly not a good idea for a server-side app, where the blocked thread could otherwise be serving other incoming client requests.

Note that with C# 5.0 / .NET 4.5 and on, APM is considered legacy. You can use [`async/await`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/async-await/info) and [`new Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) pattern, which greatly simplifies the asynchronous code development, e.g.:

```
async Task<string> ReadAllAsync()
{
    var sb = new StringBuffer();

    using (var tcp = new TcpClient())
    {
        await tcp.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Parse("localhost"), 8080).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        using (var stream = tcp.GetStream())
        {
            var bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (0 == bytesRead)
                break;
            sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer,0,bytesRead));
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

If for some reason you don't want to use `NetworkStream.ReadAsync`, you can wrap APM-style socket APIs as TAP with `Task.FromAsync`:

```
public static class SocketsExt
{
    static public Task ReceiveDataAsync(
        this TcpClient tcpClient,
        byte[] buffer)
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync(
            (asyncCallback, state) =>
                tcpClient.Client.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 
                    SocketFlags.None, asyncCallback, state),
            (asyncResult) =>
                tcpClient.Client.EndReceive(asyncResult), 
            null);
    }

    static public async Task<Int32> ReceiveInt32Async(
        this TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        var data = new byte[sizeof(Int32)];
        await tcpClient.ReceiveDataAsync(data).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
    }
}
```